# Efficiently counting lines in a file

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to count the lines in a not so small text file (multiple MBs). The answers I found here suggest this:

```
(Get-Content foo.txt | Measure-Object -Line).Lines
```

This works, but the performance is poor. I guess the whole file is loaded into memory instead of streaming it line by line.

I created a test program in Java to compare the performance:

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.function.ToLongFunction;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class LineCounterPerformanceTest {
    public static void main(final String... args) {
        if (args.length > 0) {
            final String path = args[0];
            measure(LineCounterPerformanceTest::java, path);
            measure(LineCounterPerformanceTest::powershell, path);
        } else {
            System.err.println("Missing path.");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }

    private static long java(final String path) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Java");
        try (final Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(path))) {
            return lines.count();
        }
    }

    private static long powershell(final String path) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Powershell");
        final Process ps = new ProcessBuilder("powershell", String.format("(Get-Content '%s' | Measure-Object -Line).Lines", path)).start();
        if (ps.waitFor(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES) && ps.exitValue() == 0) {
            try (final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(ps.getInputStream())) {
                return scanner.nextLong();
            }
        }
        throw new IOException("Timeout or error.");
    }

    private static <T, U extends T> void measure(final ExceptionalToLongFunction<T> function, final U value) {
        final long start = System.nanoTime();
        final long result = function.unchecked().applyAsLong(value);
        final long end = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.printf("Result: %d%n", result);
        System.out.printf("Elapsed time (ms): %,.6f%n%n", (end - start) / 1_000_000.);
    }

    @FunctionalInterface
    private static interface ExceptionalToLongFunction<T> {
        long applyAsLong(T value) throws Exception;

        default ToLongFunction<T> unchecked() {
            return (value) -> {
                try {
                    return applyAsLong(value);
                } catch (final Exception ex) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(ex);
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

The plain Java solution is ~ 80 times faster.

Is there a built-in way to do this task with comparable performance? I'm on PowerShell 4.0, if that matters.

Comment: `(Get-Content foo.txt).Count` would also work. No need to use `measure-object` for this since it is already an array. Thor's Hammer's answer would be faster than this though

Comment: @Matt Ah, didn't know that. There seems to be a difference, though. `Measure-Object` filters empty lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See if this isn't faster than your current method:

```
$count = 0 
Get-Content foo.txt -ReadCount 2000 |
 foreach { $Count += $_.count } 

$count
```

Comment: I tried comparing your version with `system.IO.StreamReader` your version is twice as fast. And is an order of magnitude faster than the OP.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a StreamReader for this type of thing. Not sure how its speed compares to your Java code but my understanding is that only a single line at a time is being loaded by the ReadLine method.

```
$StreamReader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($File)

$LineCount = 0

while ($StreamReader.ReadLine() -ne $null)
{
    $LineCount++
}

$StreamReader.Close()
```

Comment: This method actually is about 20% quicker than the accepted answer. I verify it with my 800MB csv file by using measure-command. This method takes about 7.2 seconds to count all lines while using `get-content` method takes about 9.4 seconds. Thx @ConanW.

Answer (score 0):

SWITCH was faster for my GB+ file with 900+ character length lines.

```
$count = 0; switch -File $filepath {default { ++$count }}
```